# Json от Fast API вызывает ошибку JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests, fastapi

Я отправляю от сервера на Fast API json таким образом:

```
@app.get("/crt_thd/{session}/{theme}")
def crt_thd(session, theme):
    data = exccute(f"SELECT IPS FROM users where IPS = ' {session}'")
    h = r.get(f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/session_check/ {session}").json()[0]
    if len(data[0]) == 1: 
        ids = h+theme+str(random.choice(range(1000,100000)))

        #вносим в таблицу информацию о создающемся треде
        conn = sql.connect('db.db', timeout=7)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        expression = f"""INSERT INTO THD (CREATOR , THEM , TIME_CREATING , id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"""
        params = (h, theme, gcd() , ids)
        cursor.execute(expression, params)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()


        #создаём таблицу для треда
        conn = sql.connect('db.db', timeout=7)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        expression = f"""
CREATE TABLE {ids} (
    "sender"    TEXT,
    "message"   TEXT,
    "time"  TEXT
);
            """
        cursor.execute(expression)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

        return [200]
    return [403]
```

Я делаю запрос через библиотеку requets:

```
import requests as r
session="qwerty"
h = r.get(f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/crt_thd/{session}/other")
print(h.json())
```

Запрос успешен, но при попытке взаимодействовать с json из запроса у меня возникает следующее:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>>> print(f.json())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

. C чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Вообще-то `url` у ваших запросов разный в первом случае и во втором. И в первом случае вы сразу берёте нулевой элемент от `json`, а вы уверены, что там на верхнем уровне список, а не словарь? Вы не показали ни сам `json`, ни ошибку, которая у вас выходит. Добавьте текст `json`-а прямо в вопрос, и полный текст ошибки тоже добавьте. А по пересказам ошибок тут не гадают. При таких вводных может быть всё, что угодно.

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки, ваш запрос вернул `None`. Интересный случай. А что если в `.text` ответа посмотреть и в `.content`, что там?